# jQuery does not fire on second click

Tags: jquery, onclick, click, haml

I can't figure out why the jQuery doesn't fire the second time I click the button. I'm clueless, if you need more code or anything else, just ask.

**HAML:**

The detail container which contains the button (**%input.newRemark.newEntity.tm_button{:type => "button", :value => "New"}**):

```
.detail_header_container.remark
.red_title.detail_header.open#explore_management-configurationremarks_header="Remarks"
%input.newRemark.newEntity.tm_button{:type => "button", :value => "New"}
%div.listingContainer            
  .entityDetailsContainer      
    %table.configDetails{:class => "configuration-#{entity.id}"}
      %thead
        %tr
          %th{:style => "width:25%"} Date
          %th{:style => "width:65%"} Remark
          %th{:style => "width:10%h"} Actions
      %tbody
        - ConfigurationRemark.where(:access_line_id => entity.access_line_id).sort(:created_at).each do |remark|       
          = render(:haml, :"explore_management/configurationremark_record", :locals => {:entity => remark})
```

**The modal that jQuery won't fire a second time:**

```
-# ModalContent
%div{:id => "add_remark_modal"}
  %h1 Add remark to Access ID: #{entity.access_line_id}
  %div.formErrors
  %form.remarkForm#explore_management-configurationremarks_form{:action => "explore_management/configurationremarks",  :method => "POST"}
    %input{:type => "hidden", :name => "_method", :value => "POST"}
    %input{:type => "hidden", :name => "access_line_id", :value => entity.access_line_id, :name => "entity[access_line_id]"}
    %input{:type => "hidden", :name => "isFirst", :value => isFirst, :name => "config[isFirst]"}
    %input{:type => "hidden", :name => "isLatest", :value => isLatest, :name => "config[isLatest]"}
    %input{:type => "hidden", :name => "entity_index", :value => entity_index, :name => "config[entity_index]"}
    %input{:type => "hidden", :name => "entity_array", :value => entity_array, :name => "config[entity_array]"}
    %div
      %label{:for => "remark"} Remark:
      %input{:id => "remark", :type => "text", :name => "entity[remark]"}

    %div#entityFormSubmit
      %input.tm_button.add_remark{:type => "submit", :value => "Save"}
```

**jQuery:**

```
// Click-event for dynamically added new-button(s) 
$(document).on('click', '.newRemark', function(event){
    // Open Remark popup
    $("#add_remark_modal").modal();

    // Set remark form save functions
    onRemarkFormLoadSuccess();      
});
```

---

```
function onRemarkFormLoadSuccess(data) {
    var method = $(".remarkForm").find('input[name="_method"]').val();
    var remarkFormOptions = { dataType: "html", 
                              method: "POST",
                              success: onRemarkSaveSuccess,
                              error: onRemarkSaveError                          
                            };
    $(".remarkForm").ajaxForm(remarkFormOptions);   
}
```

---

```
function onRemarkSaveSuccess(record_html, statusText, jqXhr, jqForm) {
    //remove form
    $("#simplemodal-overlay").remove();
    $("#simplemodal-container").remove();

    var headerId = jqForm.attr('id').replace('_form', '_header');
    var $listingContainer = $("#" + headerId).parent().find(".listingContainer");
    var $tableBody = $("#" + headerId).parent().find("table.configDetails tbody");
    //append new record
    $tableBody.find("tr.nothingFound").remove();
    var $newRecord = $(record_html).appendTo($tableBody);

    //fade in$

    $newRecord.hide();
    $newRecord.css('background-color', '#FFFF66');
    $newRecord.fadeIn(1000, function() { $newRecord.css('background-color', 'inherit');});

    registerRecordActionHandlers($newRecord);

}
```

---

```
function onRemarkSaveError() {

    alert("error");

}
```

---

```
function registerRecordActionHandlers($record) {
        $record.click(onRecordClick);
        $record.find(".recordActions a").click(onRecordActionClick);
}
```

**VISUAL:**

Some visual for better understanding:

[image: remarks]

---

[image: add_remark]

Comment: is there any error shown in console?

Comment: You should provide **just** relevant code in question regarding your issue. BTW, which handler give you problem?

Comment: @AnoopJoshi Nothing in the console, I've also tried with firebug.

Comment: @A.Wolff did you check his success handler? he's calling the function without parameters, but the actual function have 4 params. Is that a problem? I'm not familiar with this type of function calling.

Comment: @AnoopJoshi There is too much code to check, i'm even not sure which success handler you are talking about. If OP wants help, he must provide minimalistic code in question to replicate his issue.

Comment: @A.Wolff "on('click', '.newRemark', function(event)" isn't triggering. But, when I remove the line "onRemarkFormLoadSuccess();", then the button triggers fine.

Comment: @A.Wolff it's hard to provide minimalistic code because I can't perfectly says where the problem is located because I don't get any errors in console.

Comment: @MichielG what are these values?? (record_html, statusText, jqXhr, jqForm)

Comment: @MichielG Any online link? By not fired, do you mean even setting inside handler an alert() for example doesn't work?

Comment: @AnoopJoshi I honestly don't know, the code isn't documentated

Comment: @A.Wolff I can't believe I haven't tried that yet, I thought I did but apparently I didn't because it actually fires and shows the alert the second time I click. It doesn't show the modal. There is no online link.

Comment: @MichielG So you know now issue is with modal, you should set it outside click handler (without opening it) and open it on click handler. I'm not sure wich plugin this `modal()` is referring though.

Comment: @A.Wolff I got the issue fixed by placing "$.modal.close" before "$("#add_remark_modal").modal()". Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added the following line to my onClick() handler. It closes the remaining modals that are open. The first time I click there isn't a modal open but it's doesn't give an error so fine by me.

```
$.modal.close();
```

---

The handler:

```
// Click-event for dynamically added new-button(s) 
$(document).on('click', '.newRemark', function(event){

    //Close 
    $.modal.close();

    // Open Remark popup
    $("#add_remark_modal").modal();

    // Set remark form save functions
    onRemarkFormLoadSuccess();      
});
```